# Weird 5 second halts for Django on Kubernetes

Tags: django, kubernetes, gunicorn

We have a K8 cluster to host some of our services. These services talk with each other to exchange data over HTTPS APIs. Sometimes we have seen that the execution of services halts for 5 seconds and then continues. We experience high latency during this issue and found that API calls are stalled for 5 seconds through APM traces. I have attached screenshot of one such sample.

[image: APM Sample]

These services are running Django with gunicorn, containerised in Ubuntu images. What could be the reason of such issues? Is this related to name resolution or lookup? This even K8 related or something else totally? How can we proceed to debug this? If any additional information is required please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Are these requests from cold starts or after the service has been running for a while?

Comment: @jordanm No it is not cold start. The services were running for long time.

Comment: @NikhilJagtap What type of cluster is used? What happens to cpu/disk IO/network with nodes? Are APIs hosted inside k8s cluster or outside? Any service meshes like istio are used?

Comment: @moonkotte
No unusual behaviour on nodes. APIs are inside cluster but we call them through cloudfront. No, we don't have service mesh.

Comment: @NikhilJagtap Is there a chance to try to replicate this setup in another kubernetes cluster? Also double check that all pods in `kube-system` namespace do not have any issues with resources.

Comment: Not able to replicate it. I manually tried doing 'dig +trace mydomain.com' it got stuck on 10.100.... address sometimes. This is the address of coredns I believe which is running under kube system namespace. We tried scaling up coredns pods from 2 to 3. We still seeing similar issues again and again. How can I check if any other pod in system is having issues? @moonkotte

Comment: Well, DNS can be an issue. You can try to `kubectl rollout restart` coredns deployment first. Also check logs of `coredns` what happens in such moments. There's an article [how to troubleshoot dns in k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/). As well as with app if it's related to what you see. As for other system pods, it's more about checking their CPU/memory.